# why heroku crashed with code=H10 status 503

Tags: react-native, heroku, expo

i waste 10 hours for try to deploy my expo react-native app with mongodb and node js to heroku .

i still get

```
heroku crashed with code=H10 status 503
```

i tried all the tutorials,

my env file:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@lior.rva16.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
JWT_SECRET=LKDSLCXIOZJSIAJ768
```

my server package json:

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build:prod"
},
"engines": {
"node": "12.18.3"
},
```

my Procfile:

```
web:node index.js
```

my indes server:

```
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 const mongoURL = process.env.MONGO_URI;
 //db
 mongoose
.connect(mongoURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
 .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"));
  mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
 console.log(`DB Connection error: ${err.message}`);
 });
  ..........................
    app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
  });
```

and my full project is in https://github.com/roeigr7/LIOR

please help.. why is crash? what am i doing wrong?

my errors fom heroku:

```
    2020-12-20T20:22:10.757245+00:00 app[web.1]: > @ start /app
2020-12-20T20:22:10.757245+00:00 app[web.1]: > expo start
2020-12-20T20:22:10.757245+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-20T20:22:10.838503+00:00 app[web.1]: This command requires Expo CLI.
2020-12-20T20:22:10.904600+00:00 app[web.1]: Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? 
2020-12-20T20:23:10.866595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
 crashed" method=GET path="/nextMeet/by/5fac1f65a9e40443ccdf274b" 
 host=liormassage.herokuapp.com request_id=826c87fb-bb0e-4b72-87e5- 
  6225dfd790ca fwd="37.142.10.178" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try this https://dev.to/cpclark360/how-to-host-a-restful-node-js-server-with-mongodb-atlas-database-on-heroku-1opl to make sure mongoDB is connected to Heroku and than take a look at the error you get 2020-12-20T20:22:10.838503+00:00 app[web.1]: This command requires Expo CLI